# how to read and validate blank lines from selenium excel

Tags: java, excel, selenium

[image]

here in my code I am trying to read only the data from column "A" . Here in the screen shot I have attached how the sample data looks like. I am having an issue while reading the contents as its throwing null pointer exception because of the blank line. I need to verify the blank line as well . Please give me your thoughts

```
  public void verifyAllSupportingLogs() throws Exception {
    Sheet sheet = getFilenameSupportingLogs("c:\\DataFile");
    int rowCount = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    XSSFCell firstColumnCell = null;
    int firstColumnRowCount = 0;
    ArrayList<String> InnerArray = new ArrayList<>();
    String cellValues = null;
    String GetsupportingLogs1 = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      try {
        XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) sheet.getRow(i);
        firstColumnCell = row.getCell(0);
      } catch (NullPointerException nullPointerException) {
        System.out.println("Cell is null at index: " + i);
      }
      if (firstColumnCell != null) {
        if (firstColumnCell.getStringCellValue().length() > 0) {
          firstColumnRowCount = i;

        }
      }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j <= firstColumnRowCount; j++) {
      XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) sheet.getRow(j);
      XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(0);
      String valuesFromExcel = cell.getStringCellValue();
      InnerArray.add(valuesFromExcel);
      cellValues = InnerArray.toString();
    }
    String GetsupportingLogs = con.clickOnSupportingLogsTextbox(GetsupportingLogs1);
    System.out.println("GetsupportingLogs" + GetsupportingLogs);
    con.checkValueSupportingLogs(cellValues, GetsupportingLogs);
  }
  public void checkValueSupportingLogs(String GetsupportingLogs, String cellValue) throws Exception {
java.lang.String[] cellValue1 = cellValue.split("\n");
for (String cellValue2 : cellValue1) {
  if (GetsupportingLogs.contains(cellValue2)) {
    System.out.println("Success, this string is in the supporting logs.");
  } else {
    reportFailure("ERROR! This string is not in the supporting logs.");
  }
}
```

}

Comment: @pburgr any thoughts on this one pls ?

Comment: Iterate rows... check if row is null... iterate inside this iteration for cells... check if cell is null... use if/then... in C# it's like " if (row == null) continue;  if (row.GetCell(j) != null) {...}     POI also has a get first row function on the sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply apply same check if cell is null.

Instead of:

```
for (int j = 0; j <= firstColumnRowCount; j++) {
  XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) sheet.getRow(j);
  XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(0);
  String valuesFromExcel = cell.getStringCellValue();
  InnerArray.add(valuesFromExcel);
  cellValues = InnerArray.toString();
}
```

use this:

```
XSSFCell cell = null;
for (int j = 0; j <= firstColumnRowCount; j++) {
    XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) sheet.getRow(j);
    try {
        cell = row.getCell(0);
    }
    catch (NullPointerException nullPointerException) {
        System.out.println("Cell is null at index: " + j);
    }
    if (cell != null) {
        String valuesFromExcel = cell.getStringCellValue();
        InnerArray.add(valuesFromExcel);
        cellValues = InnerArray.toString();
        cell = null;
    }
}
```

In case if different data types in the excel file, you can combine with this: [Error : Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65384558/error-cannot-get-a-string-value-from-a-numeric-cell-in-selenium/)